# How to set a default value for XML Complex Text-Only Elements

Tags: xml, xsd

Given the XML element

```
<shoesize country="france">35</shoesize>
```

I'd like to set a default value for its integer simple content.

Now, the example above is taken from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_text.asp) and it comes with the following XSD:

```
<xs:element name="shoesize" type="shoetype"/>

<xs:complexType name="shoetype">
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
      <xs:attribute name="country" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Despite I know that a default value "can only be used if the element's content is a simple type or text only" whereas *shoesize* is a *complexType*, I struggle either to believe that I can't set such a default value to the *shoesize* or to find a way to actually do so.

In my trials, I alternatively set a default value within the shoesize xs:element, to the xs:simpleContent and to the xs:extension; none  validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also not aware of a way to set a default value beyond the cases quoted above with XML Schema only (as always, I'd be happy to be proven wrong though).

The rationale is that an element type is made of its content as well as its attributes. In the shoesize example, from a semantic perspective, the ability to set a default value only for the content could lead to inconsistencies between that default value and the country attribute, if the document specifies a country but no size (e.g., 41 populated as default for US size).

However, it is certainly possible to alter documents as part of the whole XML consumption chain, that is, with XQuery or XSLT, and set default values programmatically.

Comment: I'd be happy to see you proven wrong too, but I see your point with the consistency issue. Perhaps the designer of the spec preferred to be safe on that side, though in the specific case I have in mind it would not be a problem. Paradoxically the attributes can have a default value, so a solution would be to move the integer value into an attribute as `<shoesize country="france" size=35/>`  and `<xs:attribute name="size" type="xs:integer" default="41"/>` but that kinda breaks the logic of the XML. Good tip to set it programmatically, I might go that way.